# How can I make section background full size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the background of the section full size. I use bootstrap.

this is what i have now
[image: this is what i have now]

this is what i need
[image: this is what i need]

The code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="istorijaw2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="text-center">Istorija</h1>
      
      <p class="text-center">Žmonijai išnykus, mistiškai pradeda formuotis naujas pasaulis kitoje visatos erdvėje. Ten užsimezgusi gyvybė buvo gana primityvi. Ne, tai nebuvo vienaląsčiai organizmai nesugebantys mąstyti daugiau negu to reikia išgyvenimui, tačiau apie savo planetos
        pavadinimą jie net nemąstė, jiems ji buvo mistiška ir neištirta, dėl to visi ją vadino paprastai - Mistinis pasaulis. Šis pasaulis susidarė iš 4 bendruomenių-rasių išsibarsčiusių jame. Šios rasės gyveno atskiruose žemynuose ir puoselėjo savo miestelius.
        Apsilankius vienos ar kitos rasės gyvenamosiose vietose, galima buvo pamatyti unikalius, išskirtinius statinius atitinkančius rasės tradicijas, gabumus ir gyvenimo būdą. Mistinio pasaulio gyventojai turėjo tikslą būti geriausiems ir stengėsi bendradarbiauti
        vieni su kitais tam, kad kiekvieni iš jų sukurtų jaukų, įdomų, savo neįtikėtiną rasės miestą. Taigi, klestinčių rasių pavadinimai: Haflingai, Tabaksiai, Uritonai ir Minotaurai.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You're missing a column in your row. Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Please see [ask]. I don't see anything your markup that adds a background. Show us your attempt. Notice that you have an extra closing div tag.

Answer (score 1):

I add a class `cover-section` in your HTML as below.

```css
.cover-section {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/800) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid cover-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-center">Istorija</h1>
        <p class="text-center">
          Žmonijai išnykus, mistiškai pradeda formuotis naujas pasaulis kitoje
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want it to be with some overlay to it mate, no worries

```
 .cover-section {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), url(../to/img/) center center no-repeat;
    background-size : cover;
   }
```

Comment: You changed the container class. That should be mentioned in your explanation.

Comment: sorry i was carried mate, but hopeful it works

Comment: I don't know what that means, but my point stands. You should explain that change in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the bootstrap height and width as follows

```
.classHere{height: 100% !important; width:100% !important;}
```

use `!important` sparingly as it overrides everything in that `id/class/element` and replaces the values with the new established value.

Comment: Crap I used single quotes instead of backticks...